# Prove: if $f$ is a differentiable  function  so $\lim \limits_{n \to\infty }n^k\hat f (n)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'd love your help proving that if $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^k \hat f = 0$, where $\hat f (n)$ is the Fourier coefficient for $n$. I wanted to use the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem that $$\hat f (n)_{n \to \infty} \to  0$$ and the fact that $\hat f\,' (n)= in\hat f(n)$, and to use L’Hôpital's Theorem, but it didn't work.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is periodic over $[0,2\pi]$ and infinitely differentiable.

Then:
$$ \eqalign{ \hat {f' }(r)  
&={1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f' (t)\exp(-irt)\,dt\cr
&= {1\over 2\pi} f (t){\exp(-irt) }\Bigl|_0^{2\pi} -{1\over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}(-ir) f (t) {\exp(-irt) }\,dt\cr
&=0+  {    ir\over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f (t) {\exp(-irt) }\,dt \cr
&= {    ir} \hat{f }(r).
} 
$$

So

$$
\tag{1}ir\hat{f }(r) =\hat {f'}(r).
$$

Applying (1) with  $\hat {f'}(r)$ on the left hand side:
$$
ir\hat{f'}(r) =\hat {f''}(r);
$$
whence
$$
-r^2\hat{f }(r)=\hat {f''}(r).$$
Successive iterations yield:
$$
(ir)^n \hat {f }(r) =\widehat {f^{(n)}}(r)  .
$$

Since the Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem implies $\widehat {f^{(n)}}(r)$ tends to 0 as $r$ tends to infinity, we have that $r^n \hat f(r) $ tends to 0 as $r$ tends to infinity.

Comment: I think that there's a problem with the integration above, I think that it is suppose to be $\hat f\,' (n)= in\hat f(n)$. The function in the integral in the second row suppose to be $f''(x)$,no?

Comment: @Jozef Thanks. This was off... It should be fine now.